# Leaflet use MapTiler Vector Tiles as source

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to use leaflet with MapTiler as data source. The example states

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=...
```

However for MapTiler the URL is

```
https://api.maptiler.com/maps/.../style.json?key=...
```

How can I make this work the "non-ZXY" way?